# Python List Comprehension is not returning a new List

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am surprised by the behavior of `List Comprehension` on a `list` of `lists`. I would expect `List comprehension` to return a new list to me ALWAYS. For example:

```py
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> M = [ x * 2 for x in L]
>>> L
>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> M
>>> [2,4,6,8,10,12]
```

So `L` is not changed.

However,

```py
>>> L = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> M = [x.append(100) for x in L]
>>> M
>>> [None, None, None]
>>> L
>>> [[1,100], [2,100], [3,100]]
```

Now L is changed and `list comprehension` does not return a new List.

I am expecting a new List by the list comprehension. Any explanation would help me to understand this behavior of `list comprehension`

Comment: This has nothing to do with list comprehensions. `append` always modifies the existing list and returns None.

Comment: If you want a list with item appended returned then `[x + [100] for x in L]`

Comment: Note, the comprehension *did* return a new list, anyway.

Comment: As many have mention .append returns None, yet python allows to create a new list and add to the new one by doing the following `[x.append(100) or x for x in L]`

Comment: You might want to (re)read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: `L` did not change. The lists *contained* by `L` changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x * 2` is an expression which evaluates to a result and its result will be stored in the list `M`.

`x.append(100)` on the other hand applies function `append()` on the object `x`, which is an element of list `L` and returns `None`.

It is the same, why you do `y = x * 2`, but not `y = x.append(100)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending to `x`, is an element in `L`, that is why `L` changes. If you want a new list do not mutate a older, create a new one.

You don't specify a result you expect, but I believe this what your looking for:

```py
>>> L = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> M = [[*x, 100] for x in L]
>>> L
[[1], [2], [3]]
>>> M
[[1, 100], [2, 100], [3, 100]]
```

Comment: probable better replace the `[x, 100]` to `x + [100]`

Comment: They are equivalent. If you're talking about performance, you're just measuring nothing.

Comment: try and see the results it is not equivalent.

Comment: indeed they are not. updated to slightly different alternative than yours. which I like more, just it.

Answer (score 0):

```
x.append(100)
```

Return nothing(None), this why you have only None's inside M.